# android single activity multiple ListView scroll issue

Tags: android

Unfortunately i have used multiple ListView in single activity. At the moment i am not able to scroll till last ListView as screen height is completely occupied by other ListView's.

Is there any workaround to solve this scroll issue without much code change?.

Please help me solve this problem.

Regards,
vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split them up in separate activities. To me what you described sounds like a design flaw.

Either have `Activity A` have one `ListView`, `Activity B` the other one and so on or create one `ListView` with the content of all others and separate the content in [sections](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/).

Comment: hi octavian, Thanks for the reply. if i split each ListView's in seperate activities then how to display all of them in single activity?

Comment: then how to achieve ListView like look and feel in one screen with page scroll?

Comment: Thanks a lot octavian for the **sections** link

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** This design approach does not function reliably across configurations. When I was putting that app together I could not really find anything that indicated the downside of this approach, but here it is for any one following a similar learning path when creating an app that requires a similar design. The SO answer I linked to below is really the best approach for this situation (my opinion).

---

Sounds like the solution to your problem of multiple `ListView`'s in one `Activity` is to wrap the entire layout in a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
   . . . >
   <LinearLayout
      . . . >
      <ListView
         android:id="+@id/list_view1"
         . . . />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
      . . . >
      <ListView
         android:id=+@id/list_view2"
         . . . />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps to clarify one possible solution, if your design calls for multiple `ListView`'s to be in the same `Activity`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405211/how-to-use-multiple-listviews-in-a-single-activity-on-android/4948828#4948828) SO Question/Answer for more detail ( using a bit of a different approach, but this is where I got the idea above).

Comment: I have since realized this fact, couldn't really find anything against this approach when I was implementing the design though. I think I'll leave this answer here to help others that are in the same position that I was in.