# Two Custom ListViews inside an activity for larger displays

Tags: android, android-listview

Android 2.3.3

I have an activity where I display "Device's Contacts" in my custom view(imageview, 3 textboxes, checkbox) inside a ListView. What I want to do is, display two listviews with both showing alternate contacts (Splitting the listview into two) side by side. This is because, I want to utilize space on landscape mode of larger displays.

I haven't seen many questions on SO and somewhere I have read that, this approach will mess up scrolling of listviews and will get messy.

So, can someone explain why/how would it get messy and is there another way to use the space in larger displays in my scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this, but each ListView should be in it's own container.

Comment: Okie... I will try it. Thank you. Do you have any example or link that would have implemented this?

Comment: let me google it for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405211/how-to-use-multiple-listviews-in-a-single-activity-on-android

Comment: @ooops I think your answer which was the first should be marked as an answer. Could you do your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but each ListView should be in it's own container.
For examlple [How to use multiple listviews in a single activity on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405211/how-to-use-multiple-listviews-in-a-single-activity-on-android)

But be aware that @Rarw is more correct in the way of good programming practice. Fragments are  recommended for such purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like exactly what the [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) android tutorial was designed to address.

As @ooops mentions you will need to put each `ListView` within its own container. In the tutorial I linked to, they accomplished this by using 2 `Fragment` instances, each that loaded different content. Whether you copy their example and use the `<fragment>` tab (admitidly I don't remember which API level that works on) or use a different container like a regular `LinearLayout` you should be able to acomplish this easily.

Comment: @Vamsi Challa if you will follow this way, don't forget to add compatibility package to make this work on your 2.3.3 http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: That's right - I just checked the <fragment> on an atrix running 2.3.6. It works but you need the support library.